Does MAUI have a concept similar to Android’s Fragments
I’m porting a Xamarin Android Native app to MAUI. The app has one activity and a number of fragments. The activity displays one fragment at a time (depending on the user’s choices) but it also displays some common UI elements in a “header” and a “footer” layout. The use of fragments allows Android to take care of the UI navigation (think back button).
The only way I can see to have something similar in MAUI will be to create a content page (the activity) and number of content views (the fragments). I will have to implement the logic around swapping the content views and handling the back button.
Is there a better way to do this in MAUI?

You can refer to ContentPresenter and Shell.

I don't know what a "fragment" is ... but based on your decription, a "tabbed" control might fit your requirement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-8.0

If you look at ContentView.ControlTemplate and the fact that you can assign ControlTemplate to instantiate/modify the appearance of a ContentView would make it a candidate for a fragment.
The other thing is if you look at Grid and take into account that every child of a grid, particularly if it occupies the same Grid.Row, Grid.Column will stack into the same cell forms the basis of building a fragment manager with a stack.
// FragmentManager.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MauiFragmentDemo;

public partial class FragmentManager : Grid
{
    public FragmentManager()
    {
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (InitialFragment is not null)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () => await Push(InitialFragment));
            }
        };
    }

    public int FragmentCount => this.Children.Count;


    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Push(ControlTemplate fragment)
    {
        ContentView contentView = new ContentView()
        {
            ControlTemplate = fragment
        };
        Grid grid = new Grid()
        {
            Background = Colors.White,
            TranslationX = this.Width
        };
        grid.Add(contentView);
        Add(grid);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FragmentCount));
        await grid.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250);
        PopCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanPop))]
    public async Task Pop()
    {
        if (this.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (this.Children[Children.Count - 1] is not Grid grid)
        {
            return;
        }
        await grid.TranslateTo(this.Width, 0, 250);
        this.Children.Remove(grid);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FragmentCount));
        PopCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public bool CanPop => this.Children.Count > 0;

    public ControlTemplate? InitialFragment { get; set; } = null;
}

Here's a sample test of the above fragment manager:
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiFragmentDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiFragmentDemo"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Name="mainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonFragment">
                <Grid><Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding ., Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='Button Fragment: {0}'}" VerticalOptions="Center" /></Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="entryFragment">
                <Grid><Entry HorizontalOptions="Center" Placeholder="{Binding ., Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='Entry Fragment: {0}'}" VerticalOptions="Center" /></Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <toolkit:DockLayout>
        <Border toolkit:DockLayout.DockPosition="Top" BackgroundColor="#eee" HeightRequest="80">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Header" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border toolkit:DockLayout.DockPosition="Bottom" BackgroundColor="#eee">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" HeightRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Button Command="{Binding PopCommand, Source={Reference fragmentManager}}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Pop" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding PushCommand, Source={Reference fragmentManager}}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource buttonFragment}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Push Button Fragment" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding PushCommand, Source={Reference fragmentManager}}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource entryFragment}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Push Entry Fragment" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding FragmentCount, Source={Reference fragmentManager}, StringFormat='No. of Fragments: {0}'}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <local:FragmentManager x:Name="fragmentManager" InitialFragment="{StaticResource buttonFragment}" />
    </toolkit:DockLayout>
</ContentPage>


This example uses:

CommunityToolkit.Mvvm for the [RelayCommand] attribute
CommunityToolkit.Maui for the DockLayout component

